# How can I use a TypeScript interface in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, typescript1.6

In my project I have a TypeScript interface that I use to cast a response from an api:

```
$http.get('the url').then((response) => {
    var myData = <MyInterface> response.data;
});
```

This works great and gives me typing on the data returned from the api.

However I would like to do something similar in Protractor as I need to retrieve a static json file and cast that to the same interface so that I can manipulate data on it before running expects.

The problem is, the module where the interface lives is not available in the protractor tests so I can't use it.

I have tried to copy it to a directory in the protractor test and place it in the app.test module that the protractor tests are in but it is still invisible within the protractor class I am working on.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just export this interface to make it visible outside the module.

Comment: So how this casting looks like?
<proper.module.MyInterface> doesn't work?